# any good method to insert a control just like excel into MFC/c++ program?

Tags: c++, database, excel, gridview, mfc

I need a excel-like grid control in MFC, do anyone have good suggestion to implement that ?]
with the control i can filter the data by clicking on the header, then it will display distinct data of current column for selection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codeproject's [MFC Grid control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gridctrl.aspx) is very popular for this task. You will have to hack
it to your own needs.

For filtering and other more advanced features you might consider buying [BCGSuite for MFC](http://www.bcgsoft.com/bcgsuite.htm). 
Here is what they say about their Grid Control:

- MFC Document/View integration
- Integrated Field Chooser
- In-place cell editing
- Single and multiple row and cell selection
- Printing and Print Preview
- Filters
- Merged cells
- and more

Microsoft has added parts of BGCControlBar Pro into Visual Studio 2008 as the famous "Feature Pack" (renamed all CBCG to CMFC, changed some function names, fixed some typos), BCGSuite contains the parts they didn't sell to Microsoft.

Comment: but this can not filter data!